# Partial parsing with python ply

Tags: python, parsing, yacc, ply

Is there an easy way to perform a partial parse with python ply?
In other words: instead of parsing the entire source at once, is it possible to parse up to
the end of an expression, `yield` its result and hand back over control?

For instance, the following toy grammar produces the intended
output.

```py
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

data = '''\
a sentence.  another
sentence.
'''

tokens = ('WORD', 'DOT')

t_WORD = r'\w+'
t_DOT = r'\.'
t_ignore = ' \t\n'

lexer = lex.lex()

def p_text(p):
    '''text : text sentence DOT
            | sentence DOT'''
    p[0] = '\n'.join(p[1:-1])

def p_sentence(p):
    '''sentence : sentence WORD
                | WORD'''
    p[0] = ' '.join(p[1:])

parser = yacc.yacc()
print(parser.parse(data))      # parses all sentences at once!
```

However, how can one consume sentence per sentence (as with a generator) and not all
sentences at once?

```py
# intended behaviour: does not work!
for sent in parser.partial_parse(data):
    do_something_with(sent)
```

Comment: Normally, with standard YACC, I would propose a [pull-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895124/what-is-push-approach-and-pull-approach-to-parsing) but I don't know whether this is supported by PLY.

Answer (score 0):

Each `p_` function is invoked when the PLY parser recognizes an instance of the production in the function's docstring. So in your example, `p_sentence` is invoked each time the parser recognizes a `sentence`. If you want to pause after each `sentence`, just insert a pause into `p_sentence`. E.g.:

```py
def p_sentence(p):
    '''sentence : sentence WORD
                | WORD'''
    p[0] = ' '.join(p[1:])
    input(f"p_sentence just recognized {p[0]!r} Hit Enter to continue...")
```